# Password for locking Noted

Tags: iphone

When I try to lock’Notes’ it says ‘wrong password’, although my password unlocks normally. How can I update the password.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your old password, then it is quite straight forward to change your password.

In addition, you can reset your password, but this won’t give you access to your old notes. It will, however, let you password protect any notes that you create from that point forward with the new password. This could lead to you having multiple notes with different passwords.

1. On your iOS device, tap **Settings**

[image]

2. Tap Notes

   [image]
3. Tap Password

   [image: Tap Password]
4. You will see a Changed Password option. You can change your password if you know the original password. The other option is “Reset Password”. Tap Reset Password.

   [image]
5. You will have to enter your Apple ID password and tap OK.